# Spinner Showing in XML but Not When Loading App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have the following in my Fragment, and I am trying to create a spinner that displays numbers 1-5 as selection options:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
    mAddImageButton = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.add_image_button);
    mSelectNumberofPollAnswers = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.number_of_answers_spinner);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.number_of_poll_answers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mSelectNumberofPollAnswers.setAdapter(adapter);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
}
```

Strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="number_of_poll_answers">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>
```

XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/number_of_answers_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".3"/>
```

Comment: You need to return `rootview` from `onCreateView()`. As you have it now, you're returning a different, newly-inflated, uninitialized `View`.

Comment: Thanks! Want to submit as an answer and I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onCreateView()` method, you're returning a new, uninitialized `View` in the `return` statement. Instead, you want to return the `View` that you inflated and initialized before that. That is, change the `return` statement to:

```
return rootview;
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
return rootview;
```

Instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must return rootView like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
mAddImageButton = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.add_image_button);
mSelectNumberofPollAnswers = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.number_of_answers_spinner);
// Inflate the layout for this fragment

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =     ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        R.array.number_of_poll_answers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
mSelectNumberofPollAnswers.setAdapter(adapter);


return rootview;
}
```